# How to implement ID3

Tags: decision-trees

I'm trying to follow the suggested outline form implementing ID3

```
# Step 1- Calculate MC (Message Conveyed) for the given dataset (let us call it file TF) in reference to  the class attribute 
# MC(TF) = -p1*log2(p1) - p2*log2(p2) 
# For n classes MC(TF) = -p1log2(p1) - p2*log2(p2)-...-pn*log2(pn) 
# The probabilities are approximated by relative frequencies. 
# Step 2- Calculate Gain for every attribute in the training set . 
# Loop 1:  
 # For each attribute (Aj) Do: 
# Consider the attribute is a node from which k branches are emanating,  
# where k is the number of unique values in the attribute  
# Temporarily, split the file TF into K new files based on the unique values in the  attribute Aj. 
# Let us call these new files F1, . . ., Fk  
# Total =0; 
# Loop 2 
 # for each new file Fi Do: 
# Calculate MC for the file and call it MC(Fi). 
# Calculate weight for file Fi and call it Weight(Fi) 
Weight(Fi) = |Fi|/|TF| 
# Calculate the weighted MC (WMC) for file Fi 
# WMC(Fi) = Weight(Fi) * MC(Fi) 
# Total = Total + MC(Fi)  
# End of loop 2 
# Calculate Gain of Aj 
# Gain(Aj) = MC(TF) – Total; 
# End of Loop 1 
# The attribute with the highest gain is the winner. 
# Permanently split the file TF into K new files based on the K unique values of the winner  attribute. 
# Remove the winner attribute from all new K files. 
# Now you have the root of the tree (the winner attribute) and this tree has k leaves, and  each leaf has its own dataset.  
# Step 3- Examine dataset of each leaf.  
# If the attribute class has the same value for all the records in the leaf’s dataset,  then mark the leaf as “no split”  
else mark it as “split”.  
# Step 4- For each leaf’s dataset that is marked “Split” Do. 
# The dataset become the new TF  
TF = leaf’s dataset 
# Go to Step 1;
```

The code that I have written for this program is written as follows:

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import count
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
from math import ceil, floor, log2
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from numpy import linalg as LA
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

def calculate_metrics(tp, tn, fn, p, n, fp):
    # calculate the accuracy, error rate, sensitivity, specificity, and precision for the selected classifier in reference to the corresponding test set.
    accuracy = tp + tn /(p+n)
    error_rate = fp + fn /(p + n)
    sensitivity = tp/ p
    precision = tp/ (tp+fp)
    specificity = tn/n

    display_metrics(accuracy, error_rate, sensitivity, precision, specificity)

def display_metrics(accuracy, error_rate, sensitivity, precision, specificity):
    print(f'Accuracy: {accuracy}, Error_rate:{error_rate}, Sensitivity:{sensitivity}, Precision:{precision}, specificity:{specificity}')

def mc(columnName,training_set):
    column = training_set[columnName]
    probs = column.value_counts(normalize=True)
    messageConveyed = -1*np.sum(np.log2(probs)*probs)
    # print(f'mc {messageConveyed}')
    return messageConveyed

def isUnique(s):
    a = s.to_numpy() # s.values (pandas<0.24)
    return (a[0] == a).all()

def ID3(root,training_set,test_set):


    if(root == ""):
        # Step 1- Calculate MC (Message Conveyed) for the given data set in reference to the class attribute
        print(f'Step 1- Calculate MC (Message Conveyed) for the given data set in reference to the class attribute')
        # MC = -p1*log2(p1) - p2*log2(p2)
        # For n classes MC = -p1log2(p1) - p2*log2(p2)-...-pn*log2(pn)

        # For each column calculate the gain.
        numberOfColumns = 0
        mcDictionary = {}
        print('***********************************')
        print('For each column calculate the gain.')
        for (columnName, columnData) in training_set.iteritems():
            messageConveyed = mc(columnName,training_set)
            mcDictionary.update({columnName:round(messageConveyed)})
            numberOfColumns+=1
        print('***********************************')
        print(f'numberOfColumns {numberOfColumns}')
        print(f'mcDictionary {mcDictionary}')


        # The column with the highest gain is the root.
        print(f'The column with the highest gain is the root.')
        values = mcDictionary.values()
        max_value = max(values)
        print(f'The max value is {max_value}')
        # print(f'The max value, {max_value}, is associated with column {columnWithMaximumInformationGain}')
        val_list = list(values)
        columnWithMaximumInformationGain = list(mcDictionary.keys())[list(mcDictionary.values()).index(max_value)]
        print(f'The max value, {max_value}, is associated with column {columnWithMaximumInformationGain}')

        # select the max value from the gain array
        # this is the new root
        root =  columnWithMaximumInformationGain
        print(f'root is {root}')
        print("******************************************")
        print("**************   ROOT   ******************")
        print(f"TF is {root}**********************")
        print("******************************************")
        print(f'isUnique = {isUnique(training_set[root])}')
        if(isUnique(training_set[root])):
            return   
    
    # Step 2 - Repeat for every attribute
    print(f'Step 2 - Repeat for every attribute')
    # Loop 1
    attribute = ""
    maximum       = 0 
    for (F, columnData) in training_set.iteritems():
        print(f'processing attribute {F}')
        # Loop 2
        Total = 0
        uniques = training_set[F].unique()
        for k in uniques:
            print(f'processing branch {k} for {F}')
            # Calculate MC for column
            messageConveyed = mc(F,training_set)

            # Calculate the weight for F
            F_D    = training_set[F].count()
            TF_D   = training_set[root].count()

            weight = F_D/TF_D
            total = weight*messageConveyed
        gain = mcDictionary[root] - total
        if(gain > maximum):
            attribute = F
            maximum   = gain 
        print(f"gain: {gain} for {F}")
    
    print(f'attribute {attribute} has the max gain of {gain}')
    print(f'removing {attribute}')
    root = attribute
    print(f'new root {root} has branches {training_set[root].unique()}')
    print(f'root is {root}')
    print("******************************************")
    print("**************   ROOT   ******************")
    print(f"TF is {root}**********************")
    print("******************************************")
    unique_values = training_set[root].unique()
    datasets = []
    for unique_value in unique_values:
        print(f'processing for file : {unique_value} ')
        df_1 = training_set[training_set[attribute] > unique_value]
        df_2 = training_set[training_set[attribute] <  unique_value]
        datasets.append(df_1)
        datasets.append(df_2)

    del training_set[attribute]
    
    # Step 3 - Examine dataset of each leaf
    print(f'Step 3 - Examine dataset of each leaf')
    print(f'number of datasets {len(datasets)}')
    print("*****************")
    print("printing datasets")
    print("*****************")
    splits = {}
    all_values_same = False
    for df in datasets:
        print(f'Step 4 - for {attribute} dataset check is marked "split"')
        if(df[attribute].is_unique):
            print(f'all values are the same no split')
            all_values_same = True
        else:
            print(f'values are not unique perform split')
            all_values_same = False
            splits.update({"split":df})
        
    if(not all_values_same):
        for split in splits:
            ID3(root,split.get("split"),test_set)
    else:
        ID3(root,training_set,test_set)
            
    print("*****************")

    

 # use the training set to predict the test set.
# use the Assignment 2--Training set to extract rules and test the quality of the extracted rules against the Assignment 2-- Test set for ID3.
test_set = pd.read_csv("Assignment 2--Test set for ID3.csv")
training_set = pd.read_csv("Assignment 2--Training set for ID3.csv")

print('***********************************')
print('TRAINING SET')
print(training_set)
print('***********************************')


print('***********************************')
print('TEST SET')
print(test_set)
print('***********************************')

print(f'test_set: {test_set}')
print(f'training_set: {training_set}')

    

def BayesClassifier(training_set,test_set):
    # use the assignment 2-- training set for Bayes as the training set to classify the records of the assignment 2 test set for bayes
    X = test_set.values
    Y = training_set.values
    clf = GaussianNB()
    clf.fit(X, Y)




# prompt user to select either ID3 or Bayes classifier.
selection = "ID3" #= input("Please enter your selection for either ID3 or Bayes classification: ")
threshold = 0.9   #= input("Please enter a threshold: ")
g         = 0.05   #= input("Please enter a value for g: ")

root = ""
if(selection == "ID3"):
    ID3(root,training_set,test_set)

if(selection == "Bayes"):
    BayesClassifier(training_set,test_set)
```

The goal of this program is to classify the training data in a decision tree like so

```
           Veriety
          /       \
      Volume      Location
```

ect..

The dataset for this program are the following:
Assignment 2--Training set for ID3.csv

```
Venue,color,Model,Category,Location,weight,Veriety,Material,Volume
2,6,4,4,4,2,2,1,1
1,2,4,4,4,1,6,2,6
1,5,4,4,4,1,2,1,6
2,4,4,4,4,2,6,1,4
1,4,4,4,4,1,2,2,2
2,4,3,3,3,2,1,1,1
1,5,2,1,4,1,6,2,6
1,2,3,3,3,1,2,1,6
2,6,4,4,4,2,3,1,1
1,4,4,4,4,1,2,1,6
1,5,4,4,4,1,2,1,4
1,4,5,5,5,1,6,2,4
2,5,4,4,4,2,3,1,1
1,5,5,5,5,1,6,2,5
2,6,5,5,5,2,2,1,4
```

Assingment 2-- Test set for ID3.csv

```
Venue,color,Model,Category,Location,weight,Veriety,Material,Volume
1,6,4,4,4,1,1,1,6
2,5,4,4,4,2,6,1,1
1,6,2,1,4,1,4,2,4
1,6,2,1,4,1,2,1,2
2,6,5,5,5,2,2,1,2
1,5,4,4,4,1,6,2,2
1,3,3,3,3,1,6,2,2
1,5,2,1,1,1,2,1,2
1,4,4,4,1,1,5,3,6
1,4,4,4,4,1,6,4,6
```

I would sincerely appreciate any help with this. I do not have a clear understanding of what the end result of the program should be. If I could understand the process I'd be able to work through the program.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the exact question: at the training stage the input is the training data and the output is the decision tree, i.e. the model. At testing stage the input is the model and the test data and the output is the predicted labels for the test instances. Note that the nodes in a decision tree are not made of a variable name, it's a condition on a variable, for example "Volume>5".

Comment: Again I am working entirely on my own. All of the people working on this are either lost or have abandoned all effort. I am looking for examples, and approaches. The test set needs to be evaluated against a test set. How this happens I don't know.

Comment: we need to know which part you understand in order for people here to help you. This is why I was asking you: in case you have some confusion about how supervised learning works, I think it's too early to implement ID3 yourself. Instead you could start by using some standard library like sklean.

Comment: I understand the concept of calculating MC.

Answer (score 3):

Ok so let's start with the basics:

- ID3 is a decision tree learning algorithm. This is supervised learning, which means that every data point (or instance) has some features $x$ and a label (or class) $y$. The goal is to train a model from some labelled dataset (data which has both $x$ and $y$ provided) so that the model can later predict the label $y$ for any new instance $x$.
- A [decision tree](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-beginners-guide-to-decision-tree-classification-6d3209353ea) represents a "decision process" as a tree: starting from the root, every node represents a question about the input features $x$. By answering the questions one by one and following the path of the answers we end up with the final decision (the label). ID3 is an algorithm which builds such a decision tree from some training data. So the output of ID3 is a full decision tree. It can be represented as a list of nodes, where each node has exactly one condition about one feature and points to two other nodes depending on the answer (is the condition true or false).
- The ID3 process is recursive, it builds nodes one after the other, from the root (top) to the leaves (bottom). Every time it starts by looking at all the available features in order to select the most informative one (the one which helps the most to decide the label) at the current stage. To do that it calculates a statistical measure (for example MC here) on the current subset of data, i.e. the one obtained after filtering according to the previous nodes we went through. Technically the subset is obtained by splitting the current data at every node after selecting the condition, i.e. it's as if each node has a particular subset of training data assigned to it: the root has the full dataset, then each node filters the subset they receives, until the leaves where there's no need to split anymore.

Hope this helps clarifying the general idea.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. I am trying to figure out how to apply post-pruning to my implementation below. The goal is to remove subtrees based on the following criteria:

If (N-M)/Q < gK,
then the subtree can be removed.
N is the number of records in the Test set that are correctly classified by the rules extracted from the tree before removal of a subtree.
M is the number of records in the Test set that are correctly classified by the rules extracted from the tree after removal of the subtree.g is a parameter, and 0 <g <0.015 K is the total number of branches in the subtree

Comment: @EvanGertis this explanation is not clear: first, pruning is not done on the test set but on the training set (it belongs to the training stage), so I guess it's "training set" instead of "test set". The N-M part is clear, it represents how much do we lose (number of correctly classified instances) by removing the subtree. Q is probably the the total number of instances, I guess? And what is K?

Comment: I've created a separate question for the pruning aspect of this implementation since this question was originally designed to provide an implementation based on the outline above. 

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/104579/how-to-apply-post-pruning-methods-to-id3-decision-tree

Answer (score -1):

I figured this part out.

````
from numpy.core.defchararray import count
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
import math
from math import ceil, floor, log2
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from numpy import linalg as LA
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB


# Step 1- Calculate MC (Message Conveyed) for the given dataset (let us call it file TF) in reference to  the class attribute 
# MC(TF) = -p1*log2(p1) - p2*log2(p2) 
def mc(classAttribute,attribute,training_set):
    column = training_set[classAttribute]

    if attribute:
        column = training_set[training_set[classAttribute] == attribute] 

    probs = column.value_counts(normalize=True)
    messageConveyed = -1*np.sum(np.log2(probs)*probs)
    return messageConveyed

def wmc(classAttribute,attribute,training_set):
    attributeCount = len(training_set[training_set[classAttribute] == attribute].index)
    total          = len(training_set[classAttribute].index)
    print(f'{attributeCount}/{total}')
    return attributeCount/total


def ID3(root,training_set,test_set):

    highestGainAttribute = ""
    highestGainValue     = -math.inf
    for classAttribute, values in training_set.iteritems():
        messageConveyed = mc(classAttribute, attribute=None, training_set=training_set)
        print(f"{classAttribute} mc: {messageConveyed}")

        attributes = training_set[classAttribute].unique()
        print(f"{classAttribute}\n")
        weightedMessageConveyed = 0
        for attribute in attributes:
            weight = wmc(classAttribute, attribute, training_set)
            messageConveyed = mc(classAttribute, attribute, training_set)
            print(f"wmc({attribute}) = {weight}")
            weightedMessageConveyed += weight*messageConveyed

        print(f'wmc({classAttribute}) = {weightedMessageConveyed}')
        gain = messageConveyed - weightedMessageConveyed
        print(f'MC - wmc({classAttribute}) = {messageConveyed} - {weightedMessageConveyed} = {gain}')
        if gain > highestGainValue:
            highestGainAttribute = classAttribute
            highestGainValue     = gain
    
    print(f'winner is {highestGainAttribute} with gain of {highestGainValue}')
    root = highestGainAttribute
    leaves = training_set[root].unique()
    splits = {}
    for leaf in  leaves:
        print(f'leaf: {leaf} of root: {root}')
        if training_set[training_set[root] == leaf][root].is_unique:
            print(f'all of the records for leaf: {leaf} are the same. NO SPLIT')
            splits.update({leaf:"no split"})
            return
        else:
            print(f'all of the records for leaf: {leaf} are NOT the same. SPLIT')
            splits.update({leaf:"split"})

    for leaf,split in splits.items():
        if split == "split":
            print(f"setting {leaf} as the new dataset")
            if root in training_set:
                training_set = training_set[training_set[root] == leaf].drop(columns=root)
                ID3(root,training_set,test_set)

# use the training set to predict the test set.
# use the Assignment 2--Training set to extract rules and test the quality of the extracted rules against the Assignment 2-- Test set for ID3.
test_set_ID3 = pd.read_csv("Assignment 2--Test set for ID3.csv")
training_set_ID3 = pd.read_csv("Assignment 2--Training set for ID3.csv")

# prompt user to select either ID3 or Bayes classifier.
selection = "ID3" #= input("Please enter your selection for either ID3 or Bayes classification: ")
threshold = 0.9   #= input("Please enter a threshold: ")
g         = 0.05   #= input("Please enter a value for g: ")

root = ""
if(selection == "ID3"):
    print('***********************************')
    print('TRAINING SET')
    print(training_set_ID3)
    print('***********************************')
    
    print('***********************************')
    print('TEST SET')
    print(test_set_ID3)
    print('***********************************')
    ID3(root,training_set_ID3,test_set_ID3)
```
````